# Calling swift class method directly from javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview, hybrid-mobile-app

Hi I am trying to implement a connection between javascript and ios. I am successful in creating a connection of getting callback in ios from javascript using messageHandlers through following code

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler {

    private var webView : WKWebView?

    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        print("Message from beyond: \(message.body)")
        let jsMapper = JavaScriptInterfaceMapping()

        jsMapper.perform(Selector(("noParam")))
        jsMapper.perform(Selector(("oneParam:")), with: "firstParam")
        jsMapper.perform(Selector(("twoParams::")), with: [1, true], with: "Go Away")

        webView?.evaluateJavaScript("letSee()", completionHandler: nil)

    }

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        let  controller = WKUserContentController()
        controller.add(self, name: "xyz")

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController = controller

        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: config)
        self.view = self.webView!

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        webView!.load(request)
    }

}


<!Doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Web</title>
    <script>
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.xyz.postMessage("tem")
        function buttonClick1() {
            window.webkit.messageHandlers.xyz.postMessage("tem");
        }

        function myFunction() {

            return "Hi Shubham"
        }




    </script>
    <script src="script.js" ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>If you see this then you are working very fine</h1>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <h3 class="happy">Shubham Bhiwaniwala</h3>
    <h3><a href="support.html" >Support page</a></h3>
    <button onclick="alert('Hi Shubham, how are you?')" >Say Hello</button>
    <button onclick="buttonClick1()" >Call Me</button>
  </body>
</html>


import Foundation
@objcMembers class JavaScriptInterfaceMapping: NSObject {
    func noParam() {
        print("I got called.")
    }

    func oneParam(_ a: String) {
        print("I got \(a)")
    }

    func twoParams(_ first: [Any], _ second: String) {
//        print("I got \(first), \(second)")
        print("I got first item as: \(first[0])")
        print("I got second item as: \(first[1])")
        print(second)
    }
    func threeParams(_ first: [Any], _ second: String, _ third: Bool) {
        //        print("I got \(first), \(second)")
        print("I got first item as: \(first[0])")
        print("I got second item as: \(first[1])")
        print(second)
        print(third)
    }
}
```

I have figured out this solution of doing a method call in iOS from a javascript. But I came to know that while connecting javascript with android we can get access to object of classes present in android, inside javascript.

That means we can call functions directly from javascript and get the job done in android.

So is there any way I can get same functionality in iOS development?

Thanks

Comment: have a look at this project, https://github.com/tris-foundation/javascript

Comment: I could not find this relevant. Can you explain how is this related to my issue? Though I want the access through webview only